# Laravel routes with optional parameters and ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, routes

I am working on a user registration page and but stuck with the following issue. I am using the same view for both new registration (id will be null) and modification(id will be passed).

Additionally, I have an ajax call on the view to populate cities.

These are my routes.

```
Route::get('UserRegistration/{uid?}', 'UserRegistrationController@Page_Load');
Route::get('UserRegistration/getCityByID', 'UserRegistrationController@getCityByID');

public function Page_Load($uid = null) {
//code
}
```

This is my ajax url:

```
URL::route('UserRegistration/getStateByID')
```

When the ajax call is being made(http://example.com/UserRegistration/getStateByID?id=1 ), it invokes the first route instead of the second. However, if I remove the optional parameter ({uid?}) in the first route, everything works perfect.

Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: Routes + RESTful keywords have to be unique, I think. For instance, what happens if -- I know you'll do everything to avoid that -- `uid=getCityByID`? **There should never be a possibility of such ambiguity when defining routes.** In a case like yours, *may be switching the order of your routes may work*, since the second is more specific than the first.

Comment: Thanks @PeterKA. I haven't paid attention to it in the routes though I had the logic to filter them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards should always come last:

```php
Route::get('UserRegistration/getCityByID', 'UserRegistrationController@getCityByID');
Route::get('UserRegistration/{uid?}', 'UserRegistrationController@Page_Load');
```

```php
echo URL::to('UserRegistration/getStateByID');
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have just overlooked into the nature of wildchars. This solves the problem.